# YAML mock data references to entities not working

Tags: playframework, yaml

I have the following mockdata.yml file in my Play Framework project:

```
Account(cash):
  name: Cash
  type: CASH
  balance: 1015

Category(food):
  name: Food
  type: DISCRETIONARY_EXPENSE
  monthlyBudget: 200

Transaction(txn0001):
  account: cash
  category: food
  date: 2012-02-24
  amount: 12
```

I load this mock data when my application starts, and I can see all the records available in my database. However, the `Transaction` record has `null` in its `account` and `category` columns.

My format seems to match the example shown [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/files/data.yml), but the entity reference from `Transaction` to `Account` and `Category` isn't working.

What could be going wrong?

For reference, here are my model objects:

```
@Entity
public class Account extends Model
{
    public String name;
    public AccountType type;
    public long balance;
}

@Entity
public class Category extends Model
{
    public String name;
    public CategoryType type;
    public long monthlyBudget;
}

@Entity
public class Transaction extends Model
{
    public Account account;
    public Category category;
    public Date date;
    public long amount;
}
```

(`AccountType` and `CategoryType` are enums.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh! As soon as I posted my model classes I saw the problem. (Love it when that happens!)

Here is the solution for anyone else that runs into the same trouble: The `Account` and `Category` fields of the `Transaction` class need `@ManyToOne` annotations. As soon as I added them, it started working as expected.

```
@Entity
public class Transaction extends Model
{
    @ManyToOne public Account account;
    @ManyToOne public Category category;
    public Date date;
    public long amount;
}
```